# Visual Studio 2010 Locals Window Red Font

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, locals

One of my Debug.Assert() fails so I get a window with the call stack and I click Retry. At this point, in the Locals window, certain rows have red text instead of black text in the Value column. What does this mean?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That means those variables were updated by the previous operation. That operation might be a line of code executing, or it might be you manually changing the value as detailed in the blog referenced by @CharithJ's answer.

Comment: You will see this same behavior in the locals window and in any pinned data tips, as well.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/06/change-values-from-the-locals-window-vstiptool0102.aspx) is an explaination.

> In this case, I will change "d" to another value:
>   [image]
>
> The changed value will turn red afterward to indicate it has been
>   modified: [image]

Answer (score 5):

A row that has turned red means that the value for that expression has been modified since the last time it was evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering what the string is called to edit the colour of the Changed value text, it can be found under `Locals Window → Changed value → Foreground.`

[image]